# Directory does not contain gradle build error even though gradle build is in directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I have a project and when I try to run the main or the test directories I have no problems with the gradle build.

But now when I  try to run an android test I get this error:
Directory 'C:\Users...' does not contain a Gradle build.

I wrote a Compose Test that looks like this:

`@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class NavigationTest {

```
@get :Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()


fun startApp_showRegistrationScreen() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        MyTheme {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
    val registerString = composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.register_for_first_time)
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(registerString).assertIsDisplayed()
}
```

}`

the error:
Directory 'C:\Users\alici\MyProject\Myproject' does not contain a Gradle build.

- Try:

> Run gradle init to create a new Gradle build in this directory.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I am confused. What do I need to do?

Here the project structure:

[image: Project strucure]

Comment: Please share the full error, your build.gradle files and your project structure.

Comment: @tomerpacific added full error and project strucutre

Comment: What command are you running and what directory are you running it from?

Comment: @SimonJacobs i am right clicking on androidTest directory and then clicking 'Run 'All Tests''

Comment: @archviz_fan - Did you try running gradle init inside your project? Your build.gradle file might not be recognized. Also, did you run the command with ---stacktrace to get more details?

Comment: @tomerpacific i have tried running init, but sadly did not work. when i run with stacktrace i only get this: * Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.build.BuildLayoutValidator$BuildLayoutException: Directory 'C:\Users\alici\MyProject\Myproject' does not contain a Gradle build.

Comment: #1 You said ` or the test directories I have no problems` but then ` I try to run an android test I get this error` ?  #2 Are you using cmd, powershell or git bash to run the gradle commands?  #3 Run gradle -version before and share the result #4 I tried with [this](https://github.com/chiuki/android-hello-world) and gradle assemble responds. Try it and share the result